# Ajax to send multiple variables to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is the Javascript/ajax code :

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var specialCharacter = document.getElementById("specialCharacter");
var length = document.getElementById("length");
var username = document.getElementById("inputUsername");
var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail");
var imageLetter = document.getElementById("imageLetterId");
var imageCapital = document.getElementById("imageCapitalId");
var imageNumber = document.getElementById("imageNumberId");
var  imageSpecialCharacter =document.getElementById("imageSpecialCharacterId");
var imageLength = document.getElementById("imageLengthId");
let letterValue = 0;
let capitalValue = 0;
let numberValue = 0;
let specialCharacterValue = 0;
let lengthValue = 0;

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("PasswordRequirements").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("PasswordRequirements").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.onkeyup = function() {
    // Validate lowercase letters
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
        letter.classList.remove("invalid");
        letter.classList.add("valid");
        imageLetter.src = "./img/SVG'S/check-circle.svg";
        letterValue = 1;
    } else {
        letter.classList.remove("valid");
        letter.classList.add("invalid");
        imageLetter.src = "./img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg";
        letterValue = 0;
    }

    // Validate capital letters
    var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
        capital.classList.remove("invalid");
        capital.classList.add("valid");
        imageCapital.src = "./img/SVG'S/check-circle.svg";
        capitalValue = 1;
    } else {
        capital.classList.remove("valid");
        capital.classList.add("invalid");
        imageCapital.src = "./img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg";
        capitalValue = 0;
    }

    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
        number.classList.remove("invalid");
        number.classList.add("valid");
        imageNumber.src = "./img/SVG'S/check-circle.svg";
        numberValue = 1;
    } else {
        number.classList.remove("valid");
        number.classList.add("invalid");
        imageNumber.src = "./img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg";
        numberValue = 0;
    }

    //Validate Special Character
    var specialCharacters = /[~!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(specialCharacters)) {
        specialCharacter.classList.remove("invalid");
        specialCharacter.classList.add("valid");
        imageSpecialCharacter.src = "./img/SVG'S/check-circle.svg";
        specialCharacterValue = 1;
    }else {
        specialCharacter.classList.remove("valid");
        specialCharacter.classList.add("invalid");
        imageSpecialCharacter.src = "./img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg";
        specialCharacterValue = 0;
    }

    // Validate length
    if(myInput.value.length >= 8 && myInput.value.length <= 15) {
        length.classList.remove("invalid");
        length.classList.add("valid");
        imageLength.src = "./img/SVG'S/check-circle.svg";
        lengthValue = 1;
    } else {
        length.classList.remove("valid");
        length.classList.add("invalid");
        imageLength.src = "./img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg";
        lengthValue = 0;
    }

    if((letterValue == 1) && (capitalValue == 1) 
        && (numberValue == 1) && (specialCharacterValue == 1) 
        && (lengthValue == 1)) 
    { 
        myInput.style.borderColor = "green";
    }else {
        myInput.style.borderColor = "red";

    }
}

function submit_form() {
    if(username.value === "") {
        emptyUsername.style.color = "red"
        document.getElementById("emptyUsername").innerHTML = "*Υποχρεώτικο πεδίο";
    }

    if(email.value === "") {
        emptyEmail.style.color = "red"
        document.getElementById("emptyEmail").innerHTML = "*Υποχρεώτικο πεδίο";

    }

    if(myInput.value === "") {

        emptyPassword.style.color = "red"
        document.getElementById("emptyPassword").innerHTML = "*Υποχρεώτικο πεδίο";
        return 0;

    }

    if((letterValue == 1) && (capitalValue == 1) && (numberValue == 1) && (specialCharacterValue == 1) && (lengthValue == 1)) { 
        
        document.getElementById("TEST").innerHTML = "Password corect";
        email = email.value;
        document.getElementById("emptyEmail").innerHTML = email;
        username = username.value;
        document.getElementById("emptyUsername").innerHTML = username;
        myInput = myInput.value;
        document.getElementById("emptyPassword").innerHTML = myInput;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './includes/registration.php',
            data : {
                email: email,
                name: username,
                password: myInput
            },
            //dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Worked";
                location.href = './includes/registration.php';
            },
            error: function(data) { 
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Faild"; 
            }    
        });
        

    }else {
        
        alert("Wrong Password !\nMake sure the requirements are met!!");
        returnToPreviousPage();
        return false;

    }
}
```

html form :

```
<form id="registration-form" method="post" action="./includes/registration.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Όνομα Χρήστη</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="inputUsername" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Όνομα Χρήστη">
            <div id="emptyUsername"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Χρήστης</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="E-mail">
            <div id="emptyEmail"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Κωδικός</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" id="psw" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Κωδικός">
            <div id="emptyPassword"></div>
            <div class="container" id="PasswordRequirements">
              <br>  
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="info invalid" id="letter"><img id="imageLetterId" src="img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg" > Τουλάχιστον 1 πεζό γράμμα.</div>
                  <div class="extraInfo" >Λατινικοί χαρακτήρες [a-z].</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="info invalid" id="capital"><img id="imageCapitalId" src="img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg" > Τουλάχιστον 1 κεφαλαίο γράμμα.</div> 
                  <div class="extraInfo" >Λατινικοί χαρακτήρες [A-Z].</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="info invalid" id="number"><img id="imageNumberId" src="img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg" > Τουλάχιστον 1 αριθμό.</div> 
                  <div class="extraInfo" >Αριθμοί [0-9].</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="info invalid" id="specialCharacter"><img id="imageSpecialCharacterId" src="img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg" > Τουλάχιστον 1 χαρακτήρα.</div> 
                  <div class="extraInfo" >Ειδικοί χαρακτήρες [!@#$%^&*].</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="info invalid" id="length"><img id="imageLengthId" src="img/SVG'S/x-circle.svg" > Μέγεθος τουλάχιστον 8 χαρακτήρων έως 15.</div> 
                  <div class="extraInfo" >Ο συνδιασμός των παραπάνω πρέπει να είναι μεταξύ 8 και 15 χαρακτήρων.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
            Αποδέχομαι τους <a href="#">Όρους και Πολιτική Απορήτων</a>
          </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit_form();">Εγγραφή</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="TEST"></div>
        <div id="status"></div>
        <hr>
      </form>
```

php :

```
<?php session_start();

include_once("dbconnect.php");

$subEmail    = $_POST['email'];
$subUsername = $_POST["name"];
$subPassword = $_POST["password"];

echo "Email    :".json_encode($subEmail)."<br>" ;
echo "Username :".json_encode($subUsername)."<br>" ;
echo "Psw      :".json_encode($subPassword)."<br>";

?>
```

when i click submit while the values email , username , password in the javascript/ajax part of the code are correct they don't transfer to the php code.

When clicking the button to submit the form i am using the ajax part to redirect in the php part and see if the variables are corrct but i get null as an exit or nothing if i remove `json_encode()` and just leave the names of the variables.

Any ideas why it won't work as i intent it's my first try on something like that.

Comment: What is `email` a reference to in the line `email = email.value;`? That seems to be the source of the issue, in all the locations you repeat that pattern. Also - you shouldn't be redefining variables in that manner. If `email` holds an Element object, don't change it to a string halfway through your logic.

Comment: just give me a sec to edit the javascript part so you can see all  the code above the if .

Comment: Your code first submits the values to `registration.php` using Ajax. After that, you're making a redirect to that page using `location.href`. Are you expecting to see the posted data after that redirect? That won't work. Those are two completely different requests. The server doesn't keep the values around from the previous requests, unless you store them on the server somewhere (session/file/database). Then you need to retrieve them on later requests, if you need them.